# How to install a older version of package like liquid 2.2.2?

Tags: apt, dpkg, software-installation, downgrade

I'd like install ***liquid 2.2.2*** for jekyll. However, the latest version of jekyll is 2.3.0.
How to install a older version of package like liquid 2.2.2 in Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can downgrade your installed packages with this code :
   `dpkg -i --force-downgrade /var/cache/apt/archives/APPLICATION-NAME-#`
   **#** : means the version number currently installed.
2. you can remove your package with :
   `dpkg -r APPLICATION-NAME-#`
   and then download desired version in *.deb* format, and install it.
3. Your system generally has multiple versions of a package available in its repositories ,It means when Ubuntu updates a package, it places the new, updated package in a special updates repository. The old package is still located an Ubuntu’s main repository and can be installed with a few tricks. If you’ve installed a newer version of a package from a personal package archive (PPA), the older packages included with Ubuntu are still located in Ubuntu’s repositories.
   if you use *Synaptic* for managing your Packages, you can do this :

   - search for application you want and select it :
     [image: you can use QuickFilter to find your application, and then select it from result]
   - from menu select *Package* and select *Force Version* :
     [image: you can use Ctrl+E to use Force Version]
   - new window opened and you can select which version you want, and click on *Force Version* button :
     [image: select version from drop-box]
   - now this window closed and you return to Synaptic window, and you see the red icon inside the application checkbox, and *Apply* button now enabled, click on Apply to apply your changes :
     [image: click Apply]

**NOTE** : After downgrade this package, select it and go to *Package* menu and select *Lock Version* option. If you don’t do this, Ubuntu will try to upgrade the installed package the next time you update your installed packages.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this has to do with GitHub pages...

```
sudo gem uninstall jekyll
sudo gem install jekyll --version '= 0.11.0'
```

This will install liquid 2.4.1 (as of writing this), so you'll need to uninstall liquid (and confirm the alert about broken dependencies) before you install 2.2.2

```
sudo gem uninstall liquid
sudo gem install liquid --version '= 2.2.2'
```